# MySQLi num_rows prepared statement returning 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am calling a function in an extenal file called getTrysLeft using include_once that checks how many times a user have tried to login in the nearest 2 hours. The problem is that it always returns 0. If I run the SQL via PHPMyAdmin it returns rows but my code always returns 0. What is the error that is causing it to show an incorrect number of rows? Here are the relevant code:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php'; 
include_once 'functions.php';
```

...

```
elseif ($loginstatus == 2)
{
    $now = time();
    $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);
    $numberofrows = getTrysLeft($user_id, $valid_attempts, $mysqli); /// Calling function located in functions.php
    $error = '<p class="error">The email address and the password does not match, try again. There are currently: '.$numberofrows.' attemts.</p>'; /// Error value, here I always see "0 attempts"              
    $_SESSION['lgnerror']= $error;
    header('Location: ../login.php');
    exit();
}
```

Here are the getTrysLeft function:

```
function getTrysLeft($user_id, $valid_attempts, $mysqli)
{
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time FROM login_attempts WHERE user_id = ? AND time > ?")) 
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $valid_attempts);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $numrows;
    } 
    else 
    {
       /// Some error handling here, nothing relevant really    
    }   
}
```

So what do you say is the error? Why does num_rows return 0 even though the exact same SQL statement returns rows in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: `AND time > ?` <= ? and not `AND time = ?` are you trying to check if the time is more than `$valid_attempts`? If so, you want to use `bind_param('is'` since I think the second argument is a string and not an integer.

Comment: Yes, time schould be greater than $valid_attempts, in other words time schoukd be greater than the time was for 2 hours ago

Comment: Re-read my comment, I edited it.

Comment: No, $now is the unix time, ie a long number for example just now 1395095664. Aren´t that considered an integer?

Comment: hm... good question. I don't store time and dates in Unix format for things like that myself; I find it complicates things too much.

Comment: Try this then `AND time > (FROM_UNIXTIME(?))` it should work.

Comment: No, that didn´t work, still 0 rows..

Comment: Might be a silly question; `session_start();` is loaded? Since you're using sessions. Plus, what is your `time` column set to?

Comment: Plus, what is your `time` column set to? That could make a difference.

Comment: In the main file (two first code blocks): of course it´s loaded, in functions.php no, but there is no use for that in the functions file, right? Time is set to in the database as int(10)

Comment: You may need it in functions; try it out and see. I also asked about what your `time` column was set to.

Comment: Edited my previous answer about time, added session in the functions file, still 0 rows

Comment: Can you var_dump() all variables in your function and show it.

Comment: Instead of storing it as an `int` try using `TIMESTAMP` or `TIME` or `DATETIME` that may very well be it. You will then have to change your `bind_param` to `bind_param('is'` --- I'm leaning more towards `DATETIME`

Comment: Sorry, I have´nt done that before, could you provide any resource so I could do it or any code for doing a var_dump()?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Q: Is `user_id` really an integer? Or is it an integer value larger than 2^31? For debugging, I suggest you try bind_param with local variables set to dummy values (which you know should work to return rows). Also as a step in debugging, try returning a literal rather than $numrows, and verify that its being handled properly by the caller.

Comment: add this var_dump($user_id); and comment out your header.

Comment: Fred: I changed it to DATETIME but it only ruined the database (the reason I haven´t responded so quick now) and made my code not work so I had to reset it. Spencer: User_id is an integer, much smaller than  2^31, thanks for the debugging tips though. ICode4U: Will do this now, wait for the results..

Comment: Thank you all for the help. var_dump() did it. $user_id had the value NULL, I quickly figured it out to be unassagned (the correct varible was $theid) and changed the varible accordingly. I´m a bit embaressed it was such a simple error, but now that I know of  var_dump() it won´t happen again. I´m still in the beginning of learning PHP and I wouldn´t have solved it without you guys so thanks once again. :)